# c++ socket programming: creating multiple streams

Tags: c++, sockets, stream

I am working on an app to start multiple streams in listener and caller modes after creating sockets. Right now, if I start one stream, the process kind of hangs because the stream is waiting for data. So this is clear to me that I need to start the stream in an async kind of process, so that the rest of the app keeps working.

Do I start the stream in:

- separate threads
- separate processes using fork
- also read about select, will that work
- Does blocking/non-blocking sockets solve this problem.

This app is being done in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a library like Boost.Asio or the C function `poll()` (or `select()` which does basically the same thing) to wait on multiple sockets at once.  Either way,  you want to "multiplex" the sockets, meaning you block until any of them has data available, then you read from that one.  This is how many network applications are built, and is usually more efficient, more scalable, and less error-prone than having a thread or process for each connection.

Comment: But when I start a connection in say blocking mode, the program just waits there. Whereas I need to add more connections thru the program. If I create socket in non-blocking mode, then it polls, but gives error of no data available for reading, and closes the connection  Whereas I need the connection to be left open for as and when data comes in.

Comment: "No data available for reading" (`EAGAIN`) is not an error if the socket is non-blocking.  Just poll until there is data available, and don't read from sockets which are not marked as ready.

Comment: Thanks you John for responding. This is my first attempt at socket programming, hence these (maybe stupid) questions. So I have created non-blocking sockets (thru a webapp), and have written a separate monitoring program for the "select", which is in an infinite loop. Is this ok, or does the monitoring program have to be part of the webapp only? How else will the socket created in a webapp,, and if so, how do I spawn  now when a connection is made,

Comment: Pls ignore above, have rephrased: Thanks you John for responding. This is my first attempt at socket programming, hence these (maybe stupid) questions. So I have created non-blocking sockets (thru a webapp), and have written a separate monitoring program for the "select", which is in an infinite loop. Is this ok, or does the monitoring program have to be part of the webapp only? Created socket numbers are written to a file and both processes (the webapp and the monitoring app) can read that file, but can it work this way? Can Sockets thus created can stay beyond the scope of the applications?

Comment: The other question is that if I have to run the infinite loop in the same application, then wouldnt this but have to be in a thread, considering the app is a webapp and the rest if the app has other functions to do. MANY THANKS for all your help so far in guiding me to the correct direction.

Comment: You usually only need a single thread: it can call `poll()` or `select()` in an infinite loop, but with a timeout specified so that it can do other useful work when there is nothing to read.  But most useful things will be triggered by an incoming event (from the network usually).

Comment: Just one more question John, from googling more it seems epoll will be more efficient than select. Pls advise.

Comment: @VandanaChadha: It won't matter unless your socket count is very large.  Use whatever you find available and easy. `epoll()` is only available on a few operating systems.